# X86 - Function is undefined

Tags: assembly, x86

I am new at assembly and am trying to wrap my head around function calling in x86. I am provided the following code:

```
read_integer:

push ebp        
mov ebp, esp    

sub esp, 8 
mov dword [ebp-4], '0' 
mov dword [ebp-8], 0 

push ebx        
push ecx        
push edx        

.read_loop:
mov eax, 10     
mul dword [ebp-8] 
add eax, [ebp-4] 
sub eax, '0'    
mov [ebp-8], eax

mov eax, 3 
mov ebx, 0 
lea ecx, [ebp-4]
mov edx, 1 
int 0x80   

cmp dword [ebp-4], 10 
jne .read_loop  

ret
```

I can call the `read_integer` function using `call read_integer`. However when I try to do the same for `.read_loop` using `call .read_loop` I get the error :

> .read_loop is not defined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you should `call` `.read_loop` from anywhere? By the looks of it, it was written to be a local part of `read_integer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the dot in `.read_loop` means that the label is *local*.

It is only visible inside the same "scope" made of 2 global labels.

```
global_label_1:
    code
.local_label
    code
    jne .local_label  <=== no ambiguity, the label is locally defined, jumps to the label above
global_label_2:
   code
.local_label    <=== same name but different scope
   code
```

It's useful because the code can be copied/pasted several times in different procedures without naming conflicts.

In your case, removing the leading dot will solved it: you want it global.

```
read_loop:
mov eax, 10
...
call read_loop
```

EDIT: some assemblers also allow to access the inner label like this: `call read_integer.read_loop`

Comment: But in the example that I shared, `read_integer` is not making any calls to `read_loop`. Doesn't that defeat the purpose ? Because from what I understand, if we are not calling `read_loop` from inside `read_integer`, then we can not possibly call it from anywhere else. So whats the whole point ?

Comment: Isn't that call part of the `.read_loop function` ? I think I am having trouble function figuring out where a `read_integer` ends and `.read_loop` begins...

Comment: you're getting it, slowly: `.read_loop` is a inner label belonging to `read_integer`, not a function meant to be called from outside the `read_integer` function.

Answer (score 1):

`.read_loop` is not meant to be `call`ed. It's a label local to `read_integer` marking the start of a loop.

If you take a look at the end of `read_integer` you see:

```
cmp dword [ebp-4], 10 
jne .read_loop
```

Which will jump back to `.read_loop` as long as `[ebp-4]` doesn't equal 10. This is similar to if you had written the following in C:

```
do {
  // Whatever
} while (*(ebp-4) != 10);
```

To be able to jump somewhere you need to specify *where* to jump. Hardcoding the location would be really inconvenient, so you use labels and let the assembler figure out which address that label corresponds to.
But you might only want some labels to be visible within a certain scope (e.g. within `read_integer`). Perhaps you want to be able to use that same label name in some other function, or perhaps you just want to make it clear to whoever is reading the code that the label is local to the function. So some assemblers provide syntax for making a label local, as described by @Jean-FrançoisFabre.

Some assemblers go one step further and allow "anonymous" labels, such as:

```
1:
    jmp 2f   ; f for forwards
    ; Whatever
    jmp 1b   ; b for backwards
2:
```

Or:

```
-:
    jp +  ; this is Z80 assembly, so jp isn't a typo
    ; Whatever
    jp -
+:
```